# IPtables rules block my IP but shouldn't

Tags: iptables

I have got a blacklist in "ipset" program, it's called "evil_ips" and it contains a lot of proxies that I have downloaded and I want to block.

If I type:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set evil_ips src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set evil_ips dst -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set evil_ips src -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set evil_ips dst -j DROP
```

I'm not able to connect via ssh or ftp to my server, but yes on http (nginx server).

And if I type:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set evil_ips src -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set evil_ips src -j DROP
```

Removing "dst" it works.

Why? My home IP is not in the blacklist!

Comment: Can you add your complete iptables output to your post?

Comment: Without knowing what your home IP is and what is in the ipset, I am not sure people could answer this.  Look for cidr blocks in your hash table that could include your home.

Comment: the problem is not in the blacklist.. it's in iptables rule when I add "dst"... If i just implement the "src" ones, I'm able to connect. If I add "dst", not. Why? I really don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would replace DROP by LOG for debugging to see, if the rules match your ip in any way. And since you only want to block proxies, why not add

```
-p tcp --dport 80
```

to your rules, to avoid blocking of ssh and ftp.

Comment: thanks for answer.. anyway it's to prevent syn flood or other ports flooding

Comment: following you anser, I'm able to connect via ssh or ftp.. the problem is that I want to block all ports from attempting to connect of ips in "evil_ips"

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED! (I'm a fool.)**

The issue was in this table:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set evil_ips dst -j DROP
```

Instead of INPUT, there should be:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m set --match-set evil_ips dst -j DROP
```

So the final working rules are:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set evil_ips src -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m set --match-set evil_ips dst -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set evil_ips src -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set evil_ips dst -j DROP
```